# Find space that disappeared after failed installation

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

When installing a program (Mathematica, through a .sh script) there were some errors and the installation failed. However, I found out later that the disk space has disappeared (in fact I tried multiple times and so the space disappeared many times). There were no files in the given destination directory. How do I free this space back up? (I already tried whether rebooting would free it.) How do I detect big files that were changed recently.

Comment: can you give the script (or a link to it) as well as tell us which directory you ran it in? can you search for the filenames mentioned in the script? Can you give the exact commands you used to run the script (including any typos)?

Comment: The .sh file is 5.3 GB so I don't think there is a convenient way to share it is there? Ran it with "sudo ./Mathematica_13.1.0_BNDL_LINUX.sh". Then replied enter to go with the default location (I believe "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.1")

Comment: so a link to the file then? side point: why on earth is a *text* file 5.3 GB long?! Did they include the entirety of the code encoded as binary in the file or something like that?

Comment: @Esther, it contains everything for the installation yes. I don't think there is any link accessible without logging in.

Comment: can you provide the errors? Also quite possibly it isn't big files, but rather many small files. So detecting big files won't necessarily help.

Comment: I can't provide the exact errors without running it again which will again make space disappear (and at the moment there isn't enough left). The errors were natural language the first one about not having the right permissions. The second one about not being able to install because there was not enough space.

Comment: you can try using `ncdu` (`sudo apt install ncdu` if you don't have it yet) to see what is taking up space on your system. It doesn't really make sense that the installer would have installed files if it didn't have permissions or enough space, but possibly it left a ton of logs or something like that?

Comment: also check `/usr/local/bin`, Mathematica website claims stuff is installed there as well.

Comment: Actually, it now got weirder. I discovered new files named .14143 (or other random numbers), taking up about 6 gb each, in the directory where I started the installation from. So I thought I had solved it. I just had to delete those. So I did, which first it couldn't do completely due to the insufficient so I did it as root and now the files are gone but the space still hasn't come back. (I reboot again to see if that would free it up, but no.)

Comment: (Nothing new in /usr/local/bin I think, and definitely nothing taking large space, total is few MB).

Comment: Also ncdu disagrees substantially with Nemo on the amount of space the directory I started the install takes up. With 207.5 vs 223.8 GB (could be the whole amount that disappeared I don't remember exactly).

Comment: Hmm, maybe that is not it for a completely unrelated folder they also disagree by about 10 percent.

Comment: use `df` to see disk usage of the folder, it is definitely accurate.

Comment: I think the relevant line is: `384G  362G  2.5G 100%` (`Size  Used Avail Use%`) is it weird that Used+Avail does not add up to Size?